# NASA SIM (Space Interferometry Mission) - how mature technically it was at the moment of cancellation?

Tags: nasa, history, canceled-project, interferometry

NASA's  [SIM mission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Interferometry_Mission) was [canceled](https://science.nasa.gov/missions/sim) in 2010.

It was planned as first optical interferometer in space.

I couldn't find answer - how technically mature the mission was when it was canceled? How far it was from making flight-ready interferometer?

-Was the technical immaturity the main reason of the cancellation? If yes - what were the main technical hurdles the designers could not overcome?

-If it was "not so far from technical maturity" - was it just luck of funds? Was it considered as less priority than JWST telescope?

-Or some other reason of cancellation?

Comment: https://trs.jpl.nasa.gov/bitstream/handle/2014/13961/00-0340.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y may have some of the info you desire.

Comment: I will not edit "luck of funds". It's Freudian slip :)

Answer (score 2):

After some self research:

---

[image]
[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:SIM-Lite_2008-concept.jpg)

SIM was an ambitious mission concept of optical interferometer in space.

SIM was in development in period of 1998-2010 (in late years - as downsized SIM-Lite concept).

The main science themes SIM was planned to address:

- How rare are Earth-like planets around closest stars (in habitable zone)
- How abundand are exoplanets in general
- To study young stars evolution
- To make parallax measurements of selected objects (with several orders better precision than previous measurements) and create "astrometric grid"

Some exerpts from [article](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0807/0807.1668.pdf) of year 2008:

The spacecraft was **very complex technically**. Quote from the article:

> The SIM PQ
> instrument is an optical interferometer system with a baseline of 9 meters, and includes two “Guide” interferometers for
> spacecraft pointing Reference and a “Science” interferometer to perform high accuracy astrometric measurements on
> target stars. However, due to its high cost, the SIM PQ mission has been postponed indefinitely.
>
> SIM PlanetQuest-Light (or SIM-Lite) is a cost effective alternative concept for SIM PQ. With a smaller 6 meter
> baseline and a 30 cm Guide telescope instead of a third interferometer, SIM-Lite will still produce a large amount of the
> original SIM PQ science objectives. The overall cost of SIM-Lite, slightly above half of the SIM PQ cost to complete,
> makes SIM-Lite an attractive candidate for flying an astrometric mission by the middle of the coming decade.
>
> The primary objective for SIM-Lite (46% of the 5 year mission) is to search 65 nearby stars for exoplanets of masses
> down to one Earth mass, in the Habitable Zone. Fig. 1 shows the discovery space for planets with SIM-Lite. For planets
> with orbit between 100 days and 10 years, SIM-Lite would be better than any other technique by a factor of 100 for the
> selected 65 stars, enabling the search down to one Earth mass planet. GAIA (a European mission currently under
> development) will be limited to the search of Jupiter size planets.

About technical challenges needed to be solved, ibid:

> SIM had many technological challenges to address in order to show the mission was technically achievable. These
> challenges range **from nanometer-level control problems to picometer-level sensing problems** [3](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0807/0807.1668.pdf). Key testbeds and
> brass-board components have been designed, built, and tested during the technology development phase of SIM [4](https://113qx216in8z1kdeyi404hgf-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/153_monnier.pdf),
> resolving all the major technology challenges. Examples of such demonstrations include the System Test-Bed 3 [5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Webb_Space_Telescope), the
> Micro-Arc-second Metrology testbed [6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaia_(spacecraft)), the Kite testbed [7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_space_telescope), the Thermal-Opto-Mechanical testbed [8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atacama_Large_Millimeter_Array) and the
> Spectral Calibration development Unit [9]. The results from these series of testbeds form the evidence that the
> technological challenges faced by SIM are achievable. This technology developed for SIM PQ directly applies to the
> SIM-Lite mission.

The authors do not site TRL (technology readiness level) reached, so I wonder whether the components were tested in termovacuum cameras, etc.

Also **observation cycle was much more complex than for conventional telescope**. SIM spacecraft was designed to work in short repeating cycles, and every cycle required switching from observed object to guide stars and back. Quote (ibid):

> The sequence starts with 20 seconds of observation time
> on the target star T, during which interference fringes are being collected. The observation is followed by about 15
> seconds to slew and reposition the two Science siderostats and the optical delay line to acquire fringes on the first
> Reference star R1. After 40 seconds of observation on R1, the interferometer is pointed back to the same target star T to
> be re-observed for 20 seconds. Then, the interferometer is pointed to the second Reference star R2, we observe for 40
> seconds, and point back to the target star. We continue re-pointing and observing between the target stars and the other
> Reference stars R3 and R4. Finally, we repeat the sequence from the beginning. During the entire sequence, the Guide 1
> interferometer and the Guide 2 telescope are locked on their respective stars, monitoring changes of the instrument
> attitude in inertia space.

All these complexities were necessary to be sure the instruments are stable and the attitude is precise, if I understand correctly.

This [white paper of year 2020](https://113qx216in8z1kdeyi404hgf-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/153_monnier.pdf) summarizes:

> Due to technical delays, rising costs, and emerging competing techniques, SIM was cancelled as part of the Astro2010 Decadal Survey. High-precision astrometry using interferometers is technically difficult and has been largely abandoned in favor of more traditional architectures, relaxing stability constraints from nm-level to µm level.

---

**So, at current state - are my subquestions answered?**

> *how technically mature the mission was when it was canceled? How far it was from making flight-ready interferometer?*

Some authors state "not so far from technical maturity", but now close exactly? I haven't definitive answer yet. TRL levels of components would be good.

*Status: **Not answered currently**.*

---

> *Was technical immaturity the main reason of the cancellation of SIM?*

**One of, but not the only** (see next paragraph). Technical uncertainty and, as result, cost uncertainty were still high, as I see it. The designers of [James Webb Space Telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Webb_Space_Telescope) telescope went all the way, and you know the result.

*Status: **Partly ansvered**.*

---

> *Or some other reason of cancellation?*

**Yes**. Some SIM science themes could be addressed by other (less complex) astronomic facilities emerging in 2000-2010:

- exoplanets abundances were studied by [Kepler space telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_space_telescope) (launched in 2009).
- astrometry by [GAIA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaia_(spacecraft)) (launched in 2014). GAIA has 20 microarcseconds precision compared with 4 microarcseconds for SIM, but GAIA makes astrometry for much more stars.
- young star systems by [ALMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atacama_Large_Millimeter_Array) radio array (operational since 2011)

While SIM-Lite was still unrivaled in precision compared with other missions, I think it lost some charm because of alternatives.

*Status: **This part of the question is answered**.*